# Error method getEntity in class ClientResponse cannot be applied to given types RestFul

Tags: java, restful

Me encuentro trabajando por primera vez con **RestFul** en una aplicación, actualmente toda la conexión la hacía mediante una clase, denominada "Conexión" que abría la base de datos para hacer uso de las tablas correspondientes (`pedido`, `estado`, `franquicia`, `local`, `carta`).

Ahora se me ha solicitado que utilice **RestFul** para hacer esto mismo, para ello me he guiado por el siguiente tutorial :

[Creating RESTful Web Services in NetBeans 7 : Part 1](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices/RESTfulWebservices.html)

[Using RESTful Web Services to Implement CRUD Operations in NetBeans 7: Part 2](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices_Part2/RESTfulWebservicesPart2.htm) <-- Me encuentro aquí

[Developing an Ajax Client for RESTful Web Services in NetBeans 7 : Part 3](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices_Part3/RESTfulWebservicesPart3.htm)

He probado con la información de la Tabla `Pedido`, para que me devuelva la cantidad de filas existentes en la base de datos, para corroborar el correcto funcionamiento del **RestFul**

```
//Método para contar pedidos
    public static String contarPedidos(){
        String totalPedidos;
        totalPedidos = "0";
        totalPedidos = pedidoRest.countREST();

        return totalPedidos;
    }
```

Lo cual se divisa de forma correcta en la vista

**El problema ha surgido cuando deseo que me retorne una lista completa de los datos existentes en la tabla `Estado` para rellenar un `JComboBox`**

```
 public static void prueba(){
     EstadoREST estadoRest = new EstadoREST();

     ClientResponse respuesta = estadoRest.findAll(ClientResponse.class);
     GenericType<List<Estado>> genericType = new GenericType<List<Estado>>() {};
     List<Estado> data = new ArrayList<Estado> ();
     data=(respuesta.getEntity(genericType)); //<--Aquí se genera el error
}
```

Según el tutorial que estoy siguiendo es aquello lo que debo de hacer, pero en esa línea me salta el siguiente error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He seguido todos los pasos del tutorial, ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Descargué todas los `jar` de Jersey aquí --> [JAX-RS 2.1 / Jersey 2.26+](https://jersey.github.io/download.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondo a mi propia pregunta en caso de que alguien pasara por lo mismo:

Buscando más información al respecto, me di cuenta que el método que crea el RestFul por defecto al agregarlo al proyecto `estadoRest.findAll` puede retornar la información en **`XML`** o **`JSON`** en mi caso solo quería que retornara un Json, del tipo JsonArray (en el caso de listar Estados):

Por lo anterior:

Este era mi código:

```
//método de prueba para extraer todos los estados desde la base de datos
public static void prueba(){
     //Para poder utilizar los métodos del REST
     EstadoREST estadoRest = new EstadoREST();
     //Pretendía tomar la información retornada por findAll
     ClientResponse respuesta = estadoRest.findAll(ClientResponse.class); 
     GenericType<List<Estado>> genericType = new GenericType<List<Estado>>() {};
     //lista para guardar todos los datos que traía la respuesta
     List<Estado> data = new ArrayList<Estado> ();
     data=(respuesta.getEntity(genericType)); //<--Aquí se generaba el error
}
```

Más allá del problema donde se generaba, era que en mi caso el método que estaba intentando llamar está construido de esta manera:

```
//método almacenado en la Clase EstadoREST
public <T> T findAll(Class<T> responseType) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;
        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
    }
```

Y yo al querer que me devolviera la información en Json, estaba pasando el parámetro `responseType` de manera incorrecta, debe de ser más o menos de la siguiente manera:

```
    private static ArrayList<Estado> alEstado = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Estado estado; // <--Entity Classes from DataBase
    private static EstadoREST estadoRest = new EstadoREST(); 
    //metodo que busca y retorna todo lo de la tabla pedido desde la bd
    public static ArrayList<Estado> listarEstados()throws Exception{
        try{ 
            //se crea un array Json
            JsonArray jsonEstadoArray = Json.createArrayBuilder().build();
            //se pasa la clase que quiere que se de vuelva la info
            //en este caso va a devolver todos los estados
            //por lo mismo va a devolver un array que va al JsonArray
            jsonEstadoArray = estadoRest.findAll(JsonArray.class);

            //limpiar array
            alEstado.removeAll(alEstado);
            //comprueba que el array json no este nulo
            if(jsonEstadoArray != null){

                int tope = jsonEstadoArray.size();
                for(int i = 0; i < tope; i++){
                    //crea un objeto Json para sacar la información
                    //ya que el Json array está formado por mas de un JsonObject
                    JsonObject object = (JsonObject) jsonEstadoArray.get(i);
                    //se extrae la info de descripción de estado desde el JsonObject
                    String descripcion = object.get("descripcion").toString();
                    //lo mismo para el id de estado
                    int idEstado = Integer.parseInt(object.get("idEstado").toString());
                    //se va rellenando el array tipo Estado
                    alEstado.add(new Estado(idEstado, descripcion));
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cargar estado :" + e);
        }
        //retorna el array;
        return alEstado;
    }
```

**Resumen:**  Mi problema fue que, en mi caso, necesitaba que la información se retornara en formato `Json`, pero el tutorial mostraba el caso de que se quisiera hacer con `XML`, simplemente estaba enviando un parámetro de mala manera, estaba enviando al método `findAll` un `ClientResponse.class` como parámetro, cuando debía ser `JsonArray.class`.